# Calculating partial derivatives.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, partial-derivative

> Find the values of $n$ so that the function $v=r^n(3\cos^2\theta-1)$ satisfies the relation$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\bigg(r^2\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial r}\bigg)+\dfrac{1}{\sin\theta}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial\theta}\bigg(\sin\theta\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial\theta}\bigg)=0$$

I got, $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\bigg(r^2\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial r}\bigg)=n(n+1)r^n(3\cos^2\theta-1)$$

Also,$$\dfrac{1}{\sin\theta}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial\theta}\bigg(\sin\theta\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial\theta}\bigg)=36\sin^2\theta\cdot\cos^2\theta \cdot r^{2n}$$

Adding them together and equating it to zero gives,$$n(n+1)(3\cos^2\theta-1)+9\sin^22\theta\cdot r^n=0$$

I don't know how to get $n$ from three unknowns, please help.

Comment: Is the *nice* relation you gave supposed to be valid for all $r, \theta$? If so and if your computations are right, taking $\theta = 0$ leads to $n(n+1) = 0$ so $n \in \{0,1\}$ and then to $9\sin^22\theta\cdot r^n=0$ which can't be satisfied for all $r, \theta$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net For $9\sin^22\theta\cdot r^n=0$, $r=0$ creates trouble, but if we consider $r=0$ then $v=0$ (not much of interest).

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I think you can't take $\theta = 0$ since then you divide through $0$ in the original equation.

Comment: Take then $\theta = \pi/2$. You get the same conclusion.

Comment: @mnulb There is a mistake in your final expression. Look at the d/dr term

Comment: @NinadMunshi see https://imgur.com/6sWJ8v8

Comment: I see, my mistake

Comment: I just calculated $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ term assuming it is supposed to be $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$  on the outside instead, and I got $-6r^n(3\cos^2\theta - 1)$ which would make this solvable, so I would check with your source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a user pointed out in the comments, there is no solution for the expression as written. But consider the similar expression
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\bigg(r^2\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial r}\bigg)+\dfrac{1}{\sin\theta}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\bigg(\sin\theta\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial\theta}\bigg)=0$$
Then the final expression would read
$$[n(n+1)-6](3\cos^2 \theta -1) = 0$$
which does have a solution of $n=2,-3$. Given how chain rule questions are usually written for intro multivariable classes, I strongly suspect this is a typo. Check with your instructor.

Comment: $n=2,-3$ answer, that  matches with the Answer provided.

Comment: @mnulb Thank you! I'll edit my post